# How to match numbers with decimal points

Tags: string, lua

I want to set two separate variables to two different numbers in a string.

I used a string like "100,125" and I was able to get the two numbers, but once I changed the string to include decimals (like "100.172,125.181"), it would return the number after the decimal.

```lua
local x, y = string.match("100,125", "(%d+),(%d+)")
--this code works, making x = 100 and y = 125
```

however

```lua
local x, y = string.match("100.134,125.122", "(%d+),(%d+)")
--this did not work correctly
```

Using the latter method, I ended up with the variables x and y set to numbers after the decimals. I think I should reformat the string to something like "100.1x125.5" but I am not sure. thanks and sorry for the beginner question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%d` matches only the digits between 0 and 9. You want to match the decimal point too, so you should use the set `[%d.]` to match any digit *or* a period.

Therefore change the pattern to the following:

```
local x, y = string.match("100.134,125.122", "([%d.]+),([%d.]+)")
print(x)
print(y)
```

This correctly prints:

```
100.134
125.122
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to install the [`split` rock](https://github.com/telemachus/split/):

```
> split = require("split")
> s = "100.134,125.122"
> x,y = table.unpack(split.split(s, ","))
> x
100.134
> y
125.122
```